# Object owner / location when uploading to S3 from a lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I have a lambda which is successfully uploading objects to my bucket.  But when I try to download the object from my app it always says `404` `NoSuchKey`.  I created my lambda with Amplify and allowed authenticated users to create, read, update and delete, and guest users to read.

I've tried the `Storage.get(key)` function with `protected` | `public` | `private` option levels, but they all return a `404`.  Yet I can see the file in my bucket under the folder, ie. `myfolder/123.pdf`.

I was wondering how the current lambda method includes the logged in user / owner of the object, but I'm not sure how to debug that, as I believe the `aws-sdk` will pass that information on from my rest endpoint to the lamdba, and then to S3?

I also noticed that uploading files from the app using `Storage.put()` will add extra information to the key path, where on my lambda it does not.  Is there a way to sync up the methods from the apps `aws-amplify` methods and the lambdas `aws-sdk` ?

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const { REGION, MY_BUCKETNAME } = process.env
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: REGION })

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { body, ...rest } = event
  const payload = JSON.parse(body)
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`)

    try {
      const s3Params = {
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Bucket: MY_BUCKETNAME,
        Key:  `myfolder/${payload.id}.pdf`,
        Body: '* MY PDF AS BUFFER *',
        ContentType: 'application/pdf'
      }
      await s3.putObject(s3Params).promise()
      console.log('SUCCESS!')
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ status: 'success' }),
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'There was an error.', error }),
      }
    }
}
```

From my app:

```js
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
await Storage.get(`myfolder/${item.id}.pdf`, { download: true }) // 404 NoSuchKey
```

Comment: So I managed to get this working, ..i think.  By making the `Key` of the s3Params `protected/${event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId}/myfolder/${payload.id}.pdf`.  But this seems very manual and I havnt seen this approach in any documentation.  And Im not sure if this will come back to bite me when the app users and authentication grows.